# Security: Can I locally change (for example in chrome) a .env variable, a react state or a redux state?

Tags: reactjs, security, redux, environment-variables, google-chrome-devtools

This question is eating my soul since I've started coding in react.

Can we do that kind of stuff?

Let's say that I set my NODE_ENV in my local chrome session to "development" and... boom! I'm a superadmin in several apps

Or I set the state IS_AUTHED to "yay, i'm authed let me in"

Ok, I guess this one does not work with JWT and other auth systems, but I'm sure several react apps out there have just a state in redux or react storing the auth status. I'm scared. I code with a shadow behind me telling me states and env variables are dangerous.

Thank you guys!

EDITED:
So yes, you can edit react or redux variables on the go, and it will clearly impact the front.

But if the app is well-designed and you don't have sensitive information in the front code you should be OK. This means that every sensitive data must come from  authed connections to the server)

No idea regarding modifying env variables like NODE_ENV or how to do it but same idea: you should be safe id you don't write sensitive data behind a "NODE_ENV="development" condition

Answer (score 0):

From what i am learning from my projects we don't usually pass the node env keys if thats what you are referring to. Further what u asked of states like isAuthed well if am a developer and i am implementing things like isAuthenticated in client side i would do with help of cookies **so that user cannot change the things.** Also if want to be **extra cautious** on these i would **use session data** on server side to hold user information but again thats a wastage of storage on server side if too many users are logged in.

Comment: @Loic V please mark your answer as resolved if you are satisfied

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately it is not the case :(

My main question is if there is a way to modify the NODE_ENV, or my react state during execution.

I know in redux and react it is possible to read the status, so i'm wondering if it is possible to change it.

If a app is well designed, i wont get any data from the DB as I wont be logged, but changing these variables i should be able to see all the front by changing variables during execution.

Comment: Hi loic V as you mentioned we do can mess up with the token in react state but it will only cause trouble to the client. For exam if i changed isAuthenticated state to true i will se dashboard but whenever i request for data i will be logged out again because i don't actually have token. What i think is you do can mess up with front end but you can't do anything to server side because every time it will recheck your token.

Comment: Yep I agree it would be a mess and also i think if the app is well structured with the server the atacker will not be able to mess with the app.

Besides, do you know how to change those elements during execution time? How can we change ENV variables, state or redux state?

Comment: Env variables like db connection url and and token secret keys are kept on server side and are not sent to client and redux state can be easliy changed you can use  **redux Dev tools extension** to see how it works .Its  very helpful for developers to find errors in front end.

Comment: .env variables are kept in server side, but you have .env variables in client side also if I'm not wrong...

For example you can reach "process.env.NODE_ENV" from the client. While for example you wont be able to get process.env.SECRET if you have that one set up on your server
 
Got half of my answer, i will update the question!